# Flipping image / mirror Image

Tags: python, image-processing

I need to write a function that get an image and return a mirror image (the Y coordinate never change), without using any mirror or flip 
module from PIL.
I have to write it myself.
I'm getting an error msg:

```
IndexError: image index out of range
```

what am I missing here?

thank you.

```
from os.path import exists
import tkMessageBox, tkFileDialog
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageFilter

def flip(im):
    '''Flips a picutre horizontally, and returns a new image that is a mirror view of the original'''
    org=Image.open(im)
    new=Image.new("RGB",org.size)   
    for x in range(org.size[0]):
        a=org.size[0]
        for y in range(org.size[1]):
            pixel=org.getpixel((x,y))
            new.putpixel((a,y),pixel)
            a-=1
    new.save("new.bmp","bmp")
```

Comment: If the picture is longer than it is wide, this will most likely fail because `a` will drop below zero right?

Comment: actually it's 280x280 pixel in  my case

Comment: Please post the full error message, so we know which line you're getting an error on, instead of having to look at each place you do a `[]` and guess which one might be wrong.

Comment: Also, which version of PIL are you using? If you can require/count on 1.1.6 or later, using `orgarray, newarray = org.load(), new.load()` and then referencing `oldarray[x, y]`, etc. is much simpler, much more efficient, and often easier to debug too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing up 0-based and 1-based indexing. `x` ranges from `0` to `org.size[0]-1`. But `a` ranges from `org.size[0]` to `1`, because you start with `a=org.size[0]` and use that, without first subtracting.

Most likely the error comes from somewhere inside this line:

```
new.putpixel((a,y),pixel)
```

… on your very first call, when you try to write pixel (280, 0) in an image that only runs from (0-279, 0-279).

So, instead of this:

```
for x in range(org.size[0]):
    a=org.size[0]
    for y in range(org.size[1]):
        pixel=org.getpixel((x,y))
        new.putpixel((a,y),pixel)
        a-=1
```

Do this:

```
for x in range(org.size[0]):
    a=org.size[0]-1
    for y in range(org.size[1]):
        pixel=org.getpixel((x,y))
        new.putpixel((a,y),pixel)
        a-=1
```

But once you fix this, you're going to run into another problem. You set `a` to `org.size[0]` every time through the outer loop, instead of just the first time. And then you decrement `a` each time through the inner loop, instead of the outer loop. So, you're going to end up copying each line in the original image to the diagonal running from (279,0) to (0,279).

So, you need to do this:

```
a=org.size[0]-1
for x in range(org.size[0]):
    for y in range(org.size[1]):
        pixel=org.getpixel((x,y))
        new.putpixel((a,y),pixel)
    a-=1
```

This kind of thing is exactly why you should try to avoid modifying indices manually like this. You never get it right on your first try. On your third try, you get something that *looks* right, but crashes as soon as you try the first image that wasn't in your test suite. It's better to calculate the values instead of counting them down. For example:

```
for x in range(org.size[0]):
    flipped_x = org.size[0] - x - 1
    for y in range(org.size[1]):
        pixel=org.getpixel((x,y))
        new.putpixel((flipped_x,y),pixel)
```

While we're at it, if you can require/depend on PIL 1.1.6 or later, using the array returned by `Image.load()` is significantly simpler, and much more efficient, and often easier to debug:

```
orgpixels, newpixels = org.load(), new.load()
for x in range(org.size[0]):
    flipped_x = org.size[0] - x - 1
    for y in range(org.size[1]):
        pixel=orgpixels[x, y]
        newpixels[flipped_x, y] = pixel
```

If you can't rely on 1.1.6, you can use `getdata` to get a iterable sequence of pixels, use that to generate a new `list` or other sequence (which means you can use a list comprehension, `map`, even feed them into [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org) via, e.g., `np.array(org.getdata()).reshape(org.size)`), and then use `putdata` to create the new image from the result.

Of course `getdata` and `putdata` deal with a 1D sequence, while you want to treat it as a 2D sequence. Fortunately, the `grouper` function in the [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) docs—which you can copy and paste, or just `pip install more-itertool`—is usually exactly what you want:

```
orgrows = more_itertools.grouper(org.size[0], org.getdata())
newrows = [list(reversed(row)) for row in orgrows]
new.putdata(newrows)
```

One thing to watch out for is that `Image.open(im)` might not necessarily return you an image in RGB mode. If you just copy pixels from, say, an XYZ or P image to an RGB, you'll end up with discolored garbage or just the red channel, respectively. You may want to `print org.mode`, and possibly `print org.pixel((0, 0))` to make sure it actually has 3 channels (and they look like RGB)`.

The easiest way around that is to convert `org` before you do anything else:

```
org=Image.open(im).convert('RGB')
```

Of course some formats either don't have direct conversions or require an explicit matrix or color palette. If you get a `ValueError`, you'll have to read up on converting your input type.

Comment: thank you very much for explaining everythig so carefully!
I got into another problem - I got a red-black image instead of colorfull like the original.
you know why?

Comment: you're probably only flipping one channel of the image and not all (eg there are 3 channels in RGB)

Comment: @user1816377: Sean Connolly may be right here—or you may have a non-RGB `org` image. For example, if you open a typical GIF, you'll end up with a `P` image, where each pixel will be a single number rather than a 3-`tuple`, which you'll end up treating as the red value, and green and blue will always be 0. I edited the answer to provide some debugging ideas, and the solution if it's the most likely case.

Answer (score 19):

Use [ImageOps.mirror(image)](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/imageops.htm) to flip the image horizontally.

```
import Image
import ImageOps

img = Image.open(FILENAME)
mirror_img = ImageOps.mirror(img)
```

---

Your code is very close to working. You have an "off-by-one" error.

```
a=org.size[0]
...
new.putpixel((a,y),pixel)
```

Let's say the `org` is 100 pixels wide. Then the first time through the loop you are placing a pixel at `(100,y)`. But the pixels are indexed from 0--99. This is why (and where) you are getting a
`IndexError: image index out of range` exception.

---

Also, be careful about where in the loops you are initializing and decrementing `a`. In fact, I would suggest not using `a` at all.

Rather, use

```
w,h = org.size
for x in range(w):
    for y in range(h):
        pixel = org.getpixel((x, y))
        new.putpixel(EXPRESSION, pixel)
```

and just replace EXPRESSION with some formula for the location of pixel you wish to color.

Comment: the point is to write a code for it, that's the assigment, but tnx anyway

Comment: "The point"? Why didn't you specify this all important point in your question?

Comment: You are already using PIL. `Image` and `ImageOps` are PIL modules. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: that's the HW we got @unutbu

Comment: you right @frb, I mentioned it now in my post, I thought it's obvious.

Comment: Not really, there have been times where I have rewritten the wheel due to not knowing about an already existing method in a module :) [due to its naming or simply my own ignorance]

Comment: link is dead, can you fix it please?